# db design: efficiency consideration when adding an intermediate class into a Many-Many relationship

Tags: database, database-design, performance, many-to-many

I understand an intermediate class is often introduced to capture information in a situation where for example, a team has many players, and a player plays for many teams over the years.  The intermediate class introduced is contract with cardinality as shown:

Team -1----N- Contract -N----1- Player

Let's say however that 98% of all queries only want current information and don't care about historical information.   Given the name of a player, they want to know information about his current team, and perhaps current contract.

Given the above relationship, should all the contracts always be looked through to find the current one first, and then from there access information about the team?  Or should an optimization be made with direct linkage between the player and his *current* team?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is assured that there is only one team for each player at given time, you just add
`currentTeam` column to the `Player` table and that's it. But remember you must update it every time you update the Contracts table! And it must be done within the transaction, so that the database is kept consistent at any time.

You violate some normal form this way, but you know what and why you are doing that - for efficiency and optimization. I do this trick many times.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, that's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @Ray, you are welcome! As regards the transaction, if you manage to update the database in 1 query, you don't need to use it. You can e.g. [run 1 `update` command for more tables within one query](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85816#msg-85816), but if you need to run `insert` and `update`, then it's 2 queries and you should use transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be under the context of some kind of ORM, so I'll run with that. (Even if it isn't, keep reading.)

Objects are useful for modeling complex operations. For example, adding a new `Contract` causes all sorts of crazy things to happen to both the `Team`, the `Player`s, and various `PayCheck`s (I made the last one up, but you get the point). This is the perfect kind of thing to be handled in code than in, say, a hideously complex T-SQL stored procedure.

But when it comes to *querying*, I find that it often makes sense to write a view/SQL statement/projection that is *shamelessly tailored* to the set of information that you need to perform a function. As long as you do this for reading data, and not for writing it, then you're not really subverting your object model; you are just *looking* at it a different way, and you're just making a pragmatic observation that most of the time, you only need the information from a `IPlayerCurrentContractQuery` and not the whole list of `Contract`s within the `Player`. Since it is a method that is called a bajillion times, you've written an integration test to make sure that the SQL produces correct results, and you've looked closely at its query plan to make sure that it's not doing awful things like table scans to the database. This commonly-used screen in your app is fast and everyone is happy.

One could make the case that creating such a separate query is a premature optimization, but it probably isn't. I mean, if a player usually only has a few `Contract`s, then it might not be worth separating out the query and interface. Sucking down all of the `Contract`s from the database to loop through them and pluck out the current one is going to perform worse than selecting the right one from the database first, but if it's just a handful of `Contract`s, then a "yeah I'm fully aware it's kinda dumb but it's fast enough" approach is probably good enough, just move on. But if these `Contract`s stretch back years or are large objects, then separating out the query becomes a no-brainer.

If *that* starts performing badly because of the joins (which is unlikely unless you start seeing significant traffic), then you add a cache. And if *that* doesn't work due to lots of writes, then you can start denormalizing your database by adding a direct reference. But unless you are writing the next Facebook of baseball then YAGNI, and at that point you're sharding across servers and throwing away most of the benefits of the relational model anyway so who cares.

A similar situation is posed in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291853/why-is-orm-considered-good-but-select-considered-bad/291886#291886).

(If this question isn't about ORM, and really is just about modeling how the tables are designed, then you make sure that you have an index that covers the query that selects the current contract--such as start and stop dates--and you are pretty much done unless you have really *exceptional* scaling requirements as mentioned above. If you're writing a particular set of joins very often, then you might write a function or stored procedure to remove the boilerplate.)

That's my brain dump. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nicholas - thanks for all your thoughts.  Yah, my "slant" is ORM, specifically GRAILS GORM.  So, what I hear you saying is, if I'm "down in the database", start by optimizing with a good stored procedure for queries, if indeed the history is deep enough to even require it.  (always good to optimize only what you need).  Then, write a cache -- which I'm not familiar with -- then, denormalize with a direct reference.  Per Tomas' answer, if I start by adding a direct reference, I must take on additional transaction code.  So, I like what you said to begin with: optimize what you need.

Comment: BTW - if you haven't seen GORM - how incredibly terse it is, might google "Getting Started with Grails refcardz", and see "Relationships" section, or the more involved GORMS manual or free book, Getting Started with Grails.

Answer (score 1):

> Given the above relationship, should all the contracts always be
>   looked through to find the current one first, and then from there
>   access information about the team?

A modern query optimizer will use the most selective index first. Assuming that player_id is in that index in a usable position, the optimizer will probably find all the rows for that player first--and there won't be many, right?--then do another index scan on the contract dates to find the current contract.

If I were you, I'd create a view that returns only the "current" rows. Let application code run against that view.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I'm using MySql "underneath" and as far as I can tell its query optimizer is turned on.  I am however at a level of abstraction higher using the GRAILS ORM (GORM), which is a simplification above hibernate, and not adding views into the database directly.  However, thanks for pointing this potential optimization out (a view), as I can probably lift up the two levels of covers if necessary.