# Language Integrated Query

Tags: c#, linq

1. What is the purpose of LINQ?
2. Where LINQ can be used?
3. How necessary is it to learn the LINQ?
4. What is the best way to learn LINQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471502/what-is-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans 1 : LINQ is a uniform programming model for any kind of data access. LINQ enables you to query and manipulate data independently of data sources.

Ans 2 :
[image]
<sub>(source: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQNewbie/LINQ.JPG))</sub>

Ans of 3 question : [LINQ: .NET Language-Integrated Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb308959%28v=msdn.10%29)

Ans 4 : use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to learn linq

check this article : [LINQ FAQ for Newbie’s](https://web.archive.org/web/20111206205807/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQNewbie.aspx)

Comment: How much necessary to learn linq ?

Answer (score 0):

`Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)` is a set of features introduced in `Visual Studio 2008` that extends powerful query capabilities to the language syntax of C# and Visual Basic. `LINQ` introduces standard, easily-learned patterns for querying and updating data, and the technology can be extended to support potentially any kind of data store. Visual Studio includes LINQ provider assemblies that enable the use of LINQ with .NET Framework collections, SQL Server databases, ADO.NET Datasets, and XML documents.

best way to learn LINQ is do all the examples in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of LINQ?

A set of class include in .Net

> Where LINQ can be used?

Querying sources of data (Database, xml files ...)

- Linq To Sql : Query Databases but in this case i would recommend the Entity Framework.
- Linq To Xml : Query Xml files.
- Linq To Objects : You can Query Collections of objects in Memory

> What is the best way to learn LINQ?

Visit the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) page on MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx