# Linq, what is difference in returning data in var, list, IEnumerable and IQueryable?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I am new to Linq please guide me on some basic things.

In read some articles on Linq. Some authers fill data in var from Linq query, some fills list of custom type objects and some fills data in IEnumerable and some do it in IQuryable. I could not get what is difference in these 4 and which one should be used in which situation.

I want to use Linq to SQL. What should I use?

Comment: Are you asking, "what is linq?"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471502/what-is-linq/471592#471592

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can never *declare* that a method returns `var` - it's only valid for local variables. It basically means "compiler, please infer the static type of this variable based on the expression on the right hand side of the assignment operator".

Usually a LINQ to Objects query will return an `IEnumerable<T>` if it's returning a sequence of some kind, or just a single instance for things like `First()`.

A LINQ to SQL or EF query will use `IQueryable<T>` if they want further query options to be able to build on the existing query, with the added bits being analyzed as part of the SQL building process. Alternatively, using `IEnumerable<T>` means any further processing is carried out client-side.

Rather than focusing on what return type to use, I suggest you read up on the core concepts of LINQ (and the language enhancements themselves, like `var`) - that way you'll get a better feel for *why* these options exist, and what their different use cases are.

Comment: Thanks Jon, can you please suggest me something to read or watch on core concepts on Linq.

Comment: Well, there are various LINQ-specific books (LINQ in Action, Pro LINQ etc). My own book (C# in Depth) goes into details with regards to the language changes and a bit of background about how things like LINQ to SQL work, but it doesn't cover LINQ to SQL etc in any real depth.

Comment: Job by "using IEnumerable<T> means any further processing is carried out client-side." your mean is on server side but not on db side, right ?

Comment: @haansi: I mean within .NET. It's the client as far as the database relationship is concerned.