# How can I add a where clause to an in included entity in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables

- Person Table (Generic person table)
- Customer Table (every customer is a person)
- Address Table (every customer has an address)

I need to query the database from entity framework for a match on the person's name and city, state. This is what I have but it doesn't work unless I remove the state and city from the where clause

```
var customer = db.tbl_Person
    .Include(t => t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address)
    .Where(t => t.VendorID == person.VendorID &&
                t.FirstName == person.FirstName &&
                t.LastName == person.LastName &&
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.State == address.State &&
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.City == address.City).ToList();
```

Any help would be appreciate - I'm still fairly new to EF. As stated in my comments below, the error I get is

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var customer = db.tbl_Person
    .Include(t => t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address)
    .Where(t => t.VendorID == person.VendorID &&
                t.FirstName == person.FirstName &&
                t.LastName == person.LastName)
    .ToList()
    .Where(t => t.tbl_Customer?.tbl_Address != null &&
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.State == address.State &&
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.City == address.City).ToList();
```

Breaking up the where should ensure that the secondary part of the query is called.  Also, you need to make sure that the two intervening records are not null.

EDIT: Added the ToList() between the wheres.  Why?  Because the error in the comment reflected that Linq is attempting to use a non-parameterized field as a parameterized field to dynamically build the query.  By placing the .ToList() in between, it forces the query to run on the first subset, and then filter that set by the State and City.

Comment: still getting the same error when I try to filter out the address 
`Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.`

@octavioccl this is the error i receive for answer as well

Comment: @chris, I don't know if  your Linq to Entities provider supports to translate null-conditional to a proper expression. Try removing the first condition (`t.tbl_Customer?.tbl_Address != null`).

Comment: awesome that worked after I added the additional ToList to receive the initial data fetch. @octavioccl the null check this way worked to my surprise. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You're welcome @chris, that's because you're working with linq to objects instead linq to entities

Comment: Interesting @octavioccl - quick search led me to this stack question regarding the difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192040/linq-to-entities-vs-linq-to-objects-are-they-the-same

Answer (score 2):

I think the way of including related properties has changed a little bit on EF 7. Try this:

```
var customer = db.tbl_Person
    .Include(t => t.tbl_Customer).ThenInclude(c=>c.tbl_Address)
    .Where(...).ToList();
```

You need to use `ThenInclude` method to include your second level. Check this [reference](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes:-January-8,-2015).

### Update

I guess you are checking if `tbl_Customer` is not `null` because you have a conditional relationship between `Person` and `Customer`. Another way to check if you have a `Customer` related is using the FK property. For example if the type of `CustomerId` is `int` and a `Customer` always is related with an `Address` (a required relationship) , you can do the following:

```
var customer = db.tbl_Person
    .Include(t => t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address)
    .Where(t => t.VendorID == person.VendorID &&
                t.FirstName == person.FirstName &&
                t.LastName == person.LastName &&
                t.tbl_CustomerId != 0 && // compare with default value of your FK property
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.State == address.State &&
                t.tbl_Customer.tbl_Address.City == address.City).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @chris I updated my answer with another possible solution that came to my mind now. This way you can avoid to load unnecessary customers into memory because all the query is executed on server side.