# LINQ to Entities error occurring at run time but not in unit test

Tags: c#, json, linq, unit-testing

I am unit testing a method in one of my controllers to check that correct data is being returned with a Linq query (this may be an integration test, but the question still stands).

I am trying to follow TTD as much as possible by replicating any errors I get at run time in a test before fixing it in the code.

However, I am running into an error that only occurs during run-time execution of my application *not* during my test.

The exception I get during run-time is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToLowerInvariant()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The method under test is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetRegions(string term)
{
    var regions = from region in DbContext.Culture
                  where
                      !region.NeutralCultureFlag &&
                      (term == null || (region.NativeName + region.CultureCode).ToLowerInvariant().Contains(term.ToLowerInvariant()))
                  orderby region.Name
                  select region;

    return Json(regions.Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.CultureId,
                    text = x.NativeName + " (" + x.CultureCode + ")"
                })
    );
}
```

The fix for the error is clearly to change `(region.NativeName + region.CultureCode).ToLowerInvariant()` to `(region.NativeName.ToLowerInvariant() + region.CultureCode.ToLowerInvariant())` but I would like to get this error in my test before I fix it.

My test method is:

```
public void Test1(string term, int expectedCount)
{
    var result = _controller.GetRegions(term);

    Assert.IsType(typeof (JsonNetResult), result);
    var jsonResult = (JsonNetResult)result;

    var data = GetJsonObject<List<JsonData>>(jsonResult);
}
```

`JsonNetResult` is a custom class that extends the normal `JsonResult` so I can use Json.Net instead of the standard Json serialiser.

The `ExecuteResult` method in `JsonNetResult` looks like:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

    HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;

    if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
        response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
    if (this.Data == null)
        return;

    var scriptSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(this.Settings);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        scriptSerializer.Serialize(sw, this.Data); //error occurs here
        response.Write(sw.ToString());
    }
}
```

The exception occurs at `scriptSerializer.Serialize(sw, this.Data);`.

Is there a way to replicate the error in my unit test so I can be sure it is fixed properly following TTD principles?

Comment: Is your test connecting to the same type of database as your production?

Comment: My test is setup to use a mocked `DbContext`.

Comment: In that case, the only way to *properly* test it is to have a non-mocked context that connects to a test database - as the error is specifically found in the `LINQ` -> `SQL statement` generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your unit test uses a mocked context, you get LINQ to objects instead of LINQ to entities.

[linq to entities vs linq to objects - are they the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192040/linq-to-entities-vs-linq-to-objects-are-they-the-same)

From above link:

> LINQ-to-Objects is a set of extension methods on IEnumerable that
>   allow you to perform in-memory query operations on arbitrary sequences
>   of objects. The methods accept simple delegates when necessary.
>
> LINQ-to-Entities is a LINQ provider that has a set of extension
>   methods on IQueryable. The methods build up an expression tree
>   (which is why delegates are actually passed as Expression<>s), and the
>   provider will build up a SQL query based on its parsing of that
>   expression tree.
>
> As an example, consider the following queries:
>
> ```
>  var query1 = mydb.MyEntity.Select(x => x.SomeProp).Where(x => x ==> "Prop");
>  var query2 = mydb.MyEntity.Select(x =>> x.SomeProp).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x == "Prop");
> ```
>
> The first query is
>   will build up an expression tree consisting of a select and a where,
>   with the two lambdas actually considered as LambdaExpressions. The
>   LINQ-to-Entities provider will translate that into SQL that both
>   selects and filters.
>
> The second query inserts an AsEnumerable(), which will force the
>   remainder of the query to use LINQ-to-Objects. In that case, the
>   provider will generate SQL based on only the selection, return all
>   those records from the database, and then the filtering will occur
>   in-memory. Obviously, that's likely going to be much slower.

Comment: While link only answers are generally frowned upon, I will mark this an accepted because it is correct. For future visitors, to reproduce the error would involve an *integration* test with a real database (that could be in-memory).

Comment: Yes, in case the link goes dead or the source changes.