# Multiple sums in a single LINQ query fire multiple SQL queries

Tags: c#, linq

As a simple example let's assume we have an IQueryable named "myQueryable" with 3 columns Id, Value1 and Value2 and we write the following LINQ expression:

```
var result = myQueryable.Select(g => new 
{ 
    Value1Sum = g.Sum(b => b.Value1),
    Value2Sum = g.Sum(b => b.Value2)                                  
});
```

This will fire 2 different queries, one for each sum and then return both of them as an object like

```
{ Value1Sum = x , Value2Sum = y }
```

Is it possible to build the LINQ Expression in such a way that only one query is fired for both sums? After all they are both calculated on the basis of the same dataset..

To make it clearer, I'd expect a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2) FROM MyTable
```

but LINQ generates two queries like this(can't post the actual queries fired for security reasons):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    SUM([Extent1].[Value1]) AS [A1]
    FROM [mo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]) AS [GroupBy1]
```

..same for Value2. Please note that even if it calls the inner select "GroupBy1" there is no grouping anywhere (also in the actual queries)

Comment: But they are different columns right?

Comment: Value1 and Value2? Yes of course

Comment: I wonder how you would write a SQL that could do these both `SELECT SUM` at once

Comment: How? SELECT SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2) FROM MyTable

Comment: @jimmious It's the same as your linq query.

Comment: But in the SQL Server Profiler I see 2 queries fired, one for each of the sums.. That's my issue

Comment: @jimmious can you update your question with those profiler caught queries (simplified)?

Comment: OK I'll try (but the actual queries are naturally humongous, as Linq tends to create)

Comment: Wait a minute, if your `MyQueryable` is the representation of your table, then `g` will not have method `Sum()`.

Comment: That's correct I messed it up while editing the code to make it safe, let me fix it. Also added the SQL you asked for

Comment: You know SeM... You led me to the correct solution by noticing that. 
This here Linq creates a single query:

Comment: queryable.Select(g => new { Value1= queryable.Sum(y => y.Value1), Value2= queryable.Sum(y => y.Value2)}).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, you can do that in a single query to your database.

First, get all the values you need.

```
var values = MyQueryable.Select(item => new { Value1 = item.Value1 , Value2 = item.Value2 })
.ToList();
```

You use `ToList()` to force the query to execute. The `Select()` is only to minimize the data you query. You might as well use

```
var values = MyQueryable.ToList();
```

This is your only trip to the database.

Now that you have all data locally, you can aggregate these values.

```
Tuple<int, int> sums = values.Aggregate(
new Tuple<int, int>(0,0),
(tuple, item) => new Tuple<int, int>(tuple.Item1 + item.Value1, tuple.Item2 + item.Value2));
```

Afterwards you have a tuple `sums` where `sums.Item1` represents the sum of all `Value1` and `sums.Item2` represents the sum of all `Value2` respectively.

#### Can I use `Aggregate` directly on my `IQueryable<T>`?

Unfortunately, no. `Aggregate()` [is not supported in LINQ to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities#aggregate-methods), so you **cannot** use it on `IQueryable<T>` directly. This is why you first need to get the data locally so you have an `IEnumerable<T>`. *Then* you can aggregate the results using *LINQ to objects*. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7192084/5389131) on the distinction between the two.

Comment: `First, get all the values you need.` what if table contains billions of rows? why do I need to fetch all of them if I need only two numbers? In that case it is much much better to do 2 db trips to get sum for val1 and sum for val2 rather then 1 db trip to get billions of rows

Comment: @DmitryPavliv I get what you are saying. But you do not need only two numbers. You really need **two values for each row** otherwise you can not sum the values up. If you have **too many rows** to get them locally all at once you will need to get and sum them up in **batches** using `.Skip(entriesFinishedCount).Take(batchSize).ToList()`. See [How to loop through IEnumerable in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches). This also applies to `IQueryable`. Of course this means one query for each batch, but if you db is too big, that's it.

Comment: Reading billions of rows (even in batches) and transferring them through network is a big overhead if you need only two values. Leave db work for db. Question is not about reducing # of db trips but minimizing resources usage. You're increasing load on db, backend and network