# Understanding the basic for Linq queries

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Suppose I have a Table in my database named `Table1`. I have 3 columns in `Table1` named

```
FirstName
SurName
DOB
```

In sql I would simply do `select * from Table1` and it'll display everything from that particular table. However what I am trying to understand is how would I select all the values from this table using `Linq` in C#. `Table1` is in the database and the front-end is being developed using ASP.NET and C# I just can't seem to get my head around this. My knowledge on `linq` is very little so do excuse me if I'm making an obvious mistake

Comment: LINQ is just a query language. It isn't specific to databases. I would suggest you take a look at an ORM like Entity Framework since it can pick up a lot of the work for you. You may also want to take databases out of the question for now, just practice using LINQ on a basic in-memory array of something.

Comment: @Arran The website I am currently working on uses EF 6 I have been given the project half way through so need to get used to really quickly. I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) means Language Integrated Query - it is used to query something integrated in the language. For example, you could query a `List<>` by using `.Where()`. It has not much to do with databases actually.

Comment: @DionV. It has *something* to do with databases, although not *everything* to do with databases.  Half of LINQ is the ability to query external resources (such as databases) from a querying language that's integrated into the language.  Only half of LINQ is for querying in-memory sequences of data.

Comment: @Servy just to make my point and because I'm stubborn; no. LINQ *itself* has *nothing* to do with databases. *Extensions* such as LINQ to SQL, do. The OP does not specifically ask for either of them, meaning I gave him the definition of the most simple one.

Comment: @DionV. LINQ is a tool that can be used, among other things, to create queries that can be executed against a database.  That's not *nothing* to do with databases.  Creating a tool for writing database queries certainly has *something* to do with querying databases.  You would have been right had you said that LINQ doesn't *execute* database queries; it just builds them.

Comment: @Servy *" While LINQ is primarily implemented as a library for .NET Framework 3.5, it also defines optional language **extensions** that make queries a first-class language construct and provide **syntactic sugar** for writing queries."*. From [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

Comment: @DionV. Okay.  And?  How does a language extension that allows *database queries* to be defined using an query syntax that's built into the language proving your point, rather than mine?

Comment: @Servy Gosh; *"provide **syntactic sugar** for writing queries"*. LINQ does not always produce database queries. Extensions of LINQ produce database queries. If you look up the standard `Where<T>()` for example, it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, whereas the EF6 extension, for example, returns an `IQueryable<T>`. **There is a difference**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below links for an intro to linq

[What is Linq and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471502/what-is-linq-and-what-does-it-do)

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1

Linq provides a mean of querying data, but you still need to provide a means of Linq accessing that data - be it through Linq2Sql classes, ADO, Entity Framework, etc.

I'm a fan of Entity Framework (EF) where you set up objects that represent your data, and use a context to populate those objects.

it could look something like this:

```
public class Table1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

public class Table1Repository
{
    private readonly MyEntities _context;

    public Table1Repository()
    {
        this._context = new MyEntities();
    }

    public IQueryable<Table1> Get()
    {
        return this._context.Table1; // in effect your "Select * from table1"
    }

    public IQueryable<Table1> GetById(DateTime dob)
    {
        return this._context.Table1.Where(w => w.DOB == dob); // pulls records with a dob matching param - using lambda here but there is also "query expression syntax" which looks more like sql
    }
```

}

Note that you're performing linq queries on the context that represents the data, not the database itself.  Linq is very powerful, but you need to provide it a means of accessing data.  Even if that data is as xml, a file, a database, whatever!

Answer (score 1):

In Linq2Sql you would select all field quite simply by

Starting with a datacontext:

```
var db = new YourDataContext()
```

And after that you can do things like

```
var myData = from row
             in db.table1
             select row
```

As you indicate yourself, your knowledge is too limited. Check out this series about L2S: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EF6 you can read your table using LinqToEntity.

```
public ObservableCollection<Table1> ReadTable1()
{            
    using (YourDBContext dc = new YourDBContext())
    {
        var data = (from x in dc.Table1 
                    select x);

        return new ObservableCollection<Table1>(data);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Why are you performing a pointless projection of the data?  Just omit it if you have no operation to perform.