# Lambda expressions, loop

Tags: c#, loops, lambda

Does anyone know how I might achieve something like this through Lambda expression?

```
public static string getString(char c, int lenght)
{
    char[] temp = new char[lenght];

    for (int i = 0; lenght > 0; lenght--, i++)
    {
        temp[i] = c;
    }

    return new string(temp);
}
```

It's a small method that I loop through:

```
for (int i = 0, j = width; j > 0; j--, i++)
{
    item[i] = getString((char)(value + 48), j);
    Console.WriteLine(item[i]);
}
```

To output a triangle of a number between 1 - 9.

Example:

```
666666
66666
6666
666
66
6
```

I've never used Lambda, but would like to learn it to achieve small loops like this.

If anyone knows a place full of examples, please point me in the direction.

Comment: Lambda expressions are cheap anonymous methods; they do not replace loops.

Comment: You could use : Enumerable.Repeat("6", 6);

Comment: `new string('6', 6)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the string constructor was good info, thanks Mat, couldnt sleep so I was playing around with some ideas.

tried combining the string constructor with the enumerable.repeat, didn't get the results I was expecting, but honestly that is because I don't use Enumerable methods, so i am unsure how they do their job.

here's what i tried

int i = 5;
int j = i;char c = '6';

string[] str = Enumerable.Repeat<string>((new string(c, j--)), i).ToArray();

foreach(string s in str)
{
Console.WriteLine(s);
}

i know why it didnt work, dont know why I thought it might haha, late nights i guess

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ solution for your specific example would be the following:

```
private string GeneratePyramid(int number, int pyramidHeight)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(true, pyramidHeight).Select((n, i) => {
        return new string(Convert.ToChar(number.ToString()), pyramidHeight - i) +
            Environment.NewLine;
    }));
}
```

(Adopted some nice tricks from @Matthew Whited's answer regarding `new string(char, count)` and not having to reverse my result)

We take advantage of `Enumerable.Repeat` to create an array which
s length is equal to `pyramidHeight`, and after that we use `Enumerable.Repeat` again to create a string with the `number` repeated `i` (index) times.

The select method creates a `IEnumerable` but as mentioned we want to flatten the resulting array of strings to a single string, so we once again use `string.Concat` to do that for us.

When invoked as such:

```
Console.WriteLine(GeneratePyramid(9, 12));
```

It will print the following pyramid:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
                      .Select(i => new string('6', 6 - i));
foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Output

```
666666
66666
6666
666
66
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = (char)(size + 48);

IEnumerable<string> pyramid = Enumerable.Range(1, size)
  .Reverse()
  .Select(i => new String(c, i);

foreach(string line in pyramid)
{
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/471592/8155