# Do I really need an ORM?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, ado.net

We're about to begin development on a mid-size ASP.Net MVC 2 web site.  For a typical page, we grab data and throw it up on the web page, i.e. there is not much pre-processing of the data before it is sent to the UI.

We're now making the decision whether or not to use an ORM and if yes, which one.  We had been looking at EF2 AKA EF4 (ASP.Net Entity Framework in VS 2010) as one possibility.

However, I'm thinking a simple solution in this case may be just to use datatables.  The reason being that we don't plan to move the data around or process it a lot once we fetch it, so I'm not sure there is that much value in having strongly-typed objects as DTOs.  Also, this way we avoid mapping altogether, thereby I think simplifying the code and allowing for faster development.

I should mention budget is an issue on this project, as well as speed of execution.  We are striving for simplicity anywhere we can, both to keep the budget smaller, the schedule shorter, and performance fast.

We haven't fully decided this yet, but are currently leaning towards no ORM.  Will we be OK with the no ORM approach or is an ORM worth it?

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655/why-do-we-need-entity-objects Personally having strongly typed objects, within your pages, that can simply be mocked, is much easier for testing than having to mock things like DataSets or so forth.

Answer (score 5):

An ORM-tool isn't mandatory!

Jon's advice is sensible, but I think using DataTables isn't ideal.

If you're using an ORM tool, the object model is far simpler than a full-blown OO domain model. Moreover, Linq2Sql and [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/), for example, are straight-forward to use. Allowing very quick code changes when the database changes.

You say you won't move the data around or process it a lot, but any amount of processing will be far easier in ORM objects rather than in DataTables. Again, if the application changes and more processing is required the DataTable solution will be fragile.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not going to practice full-blow Object Oriented Programming (and by that I mean you should have a very deep understanding of OOP, not just the ability to blurt out principles and design pattern names) then NO, it's not worth going for an ORM.

An ORM is only useful if your organization is fully invested in Object Oriented application design, and thus having the problem of having an Object to Relational model mapping. If you're not fully into OO, ORMs will become some sort of nasty roadblock that your organization will then feel it doesn't need.

If your team/organization's programming style has always leaned to keeping business logic in the DB (e.g., stored procs) or sticking to a more or less functional/procedural/static approach at writing objects and methods, do away with ORMs and stick to ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1):

It sound as if you only need to show data and dont do CRUD.

I have found that ORM is not the best way to go when displaying lists that consists of data from various tables. You end up loading large objectgraphs just to get this one needed field.

A SQL-statement is just so much better at this.
I would still return lists of strongly typed objects from the DAL. By that you have a better chance of getting a compile time error when a change in the DAL is not reflected in other layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have stored procedures you need then there probably isn't that much to gain from an ORM. If not though my experience has been that working with Linq to Entites has been much faster than the traditional stored procedure/strongly typed dataset approach assuming you are comfortable with Linq queries.

If you aren't worried about mapping to an object model then Linq to SQL is even simpler to use. You certainly don't need to be using a full OO model to reap the productivity benefits.

It would disagree with Malcolm's point about having to bring back graphs, if the ORM supports Linq you can use a projection to return a flat result with just the data you want with the added advantage the query is usually simpler than the corresponding SQL since you can use relationships rather than join.

Having made the switch and become comfortable with the technology I can think of this almost no good reason not to use one, they all support falling back to SQL stored procedures if you really need to. There will be a learning curve though and in this case that may make it not worth your while.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Joe R's advice - for speed of making changes & also the speed of initial development, LINQ-to-SQL or subsonic will get you up and going in no time.

If your application is really this simple and it's just a straight data out/data in direct mapping to the tables, have you considered looking at [ASP.net dynamic data](http://www.asp.net/(S(y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2))/DynamicData/)?

I'd also point to a good [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx) about this by Scott Guthrie.

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on how familiar you are with ORMs.

I personally think that NHibernate, which is the king of ORMs in the .NET world, allows much more rapid development as once set up, you can pretty much forget about how you are getting data out of the database.

However, there is a steep learning curve to it, especially if you try and do things in a non-hacky way (which you should), so if your team doesn't have experience here and time is pressing then it probably won't cut it.

Linq2SQL is way too simple. Don't know about Subsonic, but if you are going to use an ORM it may be a good balance between having rapid development and getting something too powerful and complex.

Ultimately though, as a team, I think you want to learn NHibernate which is not time consuming to set up on a small to medium project once you know what you are doing, but is very powerful.